# Whenever I try to search for a record I am met with an error saying that the CustomerID column doesn't exist in the searchDataService function

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

def ServiceData():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("Service.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS service(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, CustomerID INTEGER, ServiceName text, ServicePrice text, Date text, Time text, ExtraProducts text)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def addServiceRec(CustomerID, ServiceName, ServicePrice, Date, Time, ExtraProducts ):
    conn=sqlite3.connect("Service.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Service VALUES (NULL, ?,?,?,?,?,?)", (CustomerID, ServiceName, ServicePrice, Date, Time, ExtraProducts))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def searchDataService(CustomerID): 
    conn=sqlite3.connect("Service.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Service WHERE CustomerID=?", (CustomerID,))
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows
```

when ran in the front-end I am told that the CustomerID column by which it searches does not exist yet it is created above this function.

```
ServiceData()
```

Error: cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Service WHERE CustomerID=?", (CustomerID,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: CustomerID

Front end

```
        def search():
            Customerlist.delete(0,END)
            for rows in cusDatabase_BackEnd.searchData(ID_entry.get()):
                rows = list(rows)
                for i in range(len(rows)):
                    rows[i] = str(rows[i]).strip()
                Customerlist.insert(END,rows,str(""))

        CustomerID = IntVar()
        label= Label(window, text="Customer's ID:", font=('arial',13,'bold'))
        label.place(x=30, y=100)
        ID_entry=ttk.Entry(window, textvariable = CustomerID)
        ID_entry.place(x=210,y=100)
        ID_entry.focus()


        btnSearch2 = tk.Button(window, text="Search record", command = search)
        btnSearch2.place(x=1150,y=160, width=125, height=50)
```

Comment: Post the full error traceback and a [mre].

Comment: Cannot reproduce issue if `ServiceData()` and `addServiceRec(...)` are executed before `searchDataService(...)`.  So better post a [mre], that is how you call those functions.